# Що таке "кулько" в "Їхав вуйко на ровері, кулько сі спустило" -- велосипедна камера? ("Рок-н-рол до рана", Брати Гадюкіни)

Tags: значення-слів

Цікаво, що означає слово "кулько" у пісні "[Рок-н-рол до рана](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEISQiH_qWQ)":

> Їхав вуйко на ровері
> **Кулько** сі спустило
> Робітник і селянин
> То велика сила

Судячи з контексту – це велосипедна камера. Це знову діалектизм, що зараз рідко використовується?

Я знайшов слово "[кулька](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0)" в УКРЛІТ, але це не зовсім велосипедна камера.

Comment: Цілком може бути, що це просто власні асоціації автора: велосипедна камера — щось «гумове», надуте повітрям, — (повітряна) кулька. Хоча, може, й справді десь локально велосипедні камери (чи принаймні ширший діапазон виробів, ніж по Україні загалом) ку́льками називають…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово не дуже знаходиться, бо зазвичай воно без мякого знака, тобто ***кулко***.

> <sup>[Тлумачний словник української мови](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE)</sup>
>
> 1. Кільце.
>
>    - *За мідне кулко ляду підняв і задихнувся від липового медвяного духу*. (Є. Пашковський)
>    - *Ззаду заплетена одна косичка була скручена в кулко*. (із журн.)
> 2. Колесо.
>
>    - *А Місько тікав на ровері, німака [німець] йму [йому] кулко пробив.* (Ю. Покальчук)
>    - *Під час одного з роз'їздів на вузькій дорозі праве переднє кулко провалилося в канаву, яка була притрушена снігом*. (із журн.)

> <sup>[Лексикон львівський](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:N5RNrtHFCsoJ:slovopedia.org.ua/101/53402/1063935.html&cd=9&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua&lr=-lang_ru)</sup>
>
> 1. коло; кільце / обарінок
> 2. предмет, річ у формі кола; колесо:
>
>    - *А Місько хтів втікти ровером, німак йому ку́лко спусти́в* (із пісні)
>
>    ♢ *потрібне <тобі́> як ку́лко від рове́ра* цілком не потрібне / *потрібний як псу пʼята нога*

Тут, очевидно, значить *колесо*. Вираз [*спустило(ся) колесо*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%22) досить поширений стосовно шин.

Можна окремо зазначити, що [*кулько*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Ib1KZe2b8AEJ:lang.slovopedia.org.ua/10/53402/117286.html&cd=9&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua&lr=-lang_ru), що зі знаком мякости, зазвичай значить *скільки*. Оба слова мають подібну ситуацію, що і з [*удти*](/a/7261/585), тобто зміна ***о*** на гинший звук, в стандартній українській — з ***і***, тут — з ***у***.